# How to clean a json object created by "json_object_new_string"?

Tags: c, json, json-c

I have the following code and I want to clean a json object created by `json_object_new_string()`.

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  /*Creating a json object*/
  json_object * jobj = json_object_new_object();

  /*Creating a json string*/
  json_object *jstring = json_object_new_string("Joys of Programming");


  /*Form the json object*/
  json_object_object_add(jobj,"Site Name", jstring);

  /*Now printing the json object*/
  printf ("The json object created: %sn",json_object_to_json_string(jobj));

  /* clean the json object */
  json_object_put(jobj);

}
```

Does the line `json_object_put(jobj);` clean both `jobj` and `jstring` ?

Or I have to a clean `jstring` alone with `json_object_put(jstring);`?

**Edit**

**question2**

what will be the behaviour if the `jstring` is creted into a function in this way?

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void my_json_add_obj(json_object *jobj, char *name, char *val) {
      /*Creating a json string*/
      json_object *jstring = json_object_new_string(val);


      /*Form the json object*/
      json_object_object_add(jobj,name, jstring);
}

int main() {
  /*Creating a json object*/
  json_object * jobj = json_object_new_object();

  my_json_add_obj(jobj, "Site Name", "Joys of Programming")

  /*Now printing the json object*/
  printf ("The json object created: %sn",json_object_to_json_string(jobj));

  /* clean the json object */
  json_object_put(jobj);

}
```

the `jstring` in this case is a local variable into a function. Does the `json_object_put(jobj);` will clean the `jstring` (created in the function `my_json_add_obj()`) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`json_object_put` will free everything referenced by the object. So yes, it's sufficient to use that function on `jobj` to free the whole object.

Comment: what will be the behaviour if the `jstring` is creted into a function? please refer to the question I edited it

Comment: Please stop doing this. It is not acceptable Stack Overflow behavior to completely change a question after someone has posted an answer. Anyway, it doesn't matter where you do it. As long as the string is part of the object it will be free'd with it.