# Do I have to free json_object returned by json_tokener_parse?

Tags: json-c

I'm experimenting memory errors in my C application and using valgrind, I see many strange things around the json-c lib.

So looking at some infos on the web, I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382897/how-to-clean-a-json-object-created-by-json-object-new-string) about `json_object_new_object`

So I have 2 questions to be clear about everything:
The first one is about json construction

When I add an object to another object, do I have to just free the first one ?
example:

```
json_object * jobj1 = json_object_new_object();
json_object * jobj2 = json_object_new_object();

json_object_object_add(jobj1,"Object", jobj2);

...

json_object_put(jobj); // Is it enough to free all the json tree??
```

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338425/memory-leak-in-json-c) it seems to be ok, but it hasn't been really answered.

Question 2:
Looking at this [tuto](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/json_parser_json-c/), it seems not necessary to free anything but looking at my valgrind log, `json_object_new_object` is called:

```
by 0x4F7F4CF: json_object_new_object (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.3.0.1)
by 0x4F81B38: json_tokener_parse_ex (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.3.0.1)
by 0x4F82316: json_tokener_parse_verbose (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.3.0.1)
by 0x4F8237D: json_tokener_parse (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.3.0.1)
```

So do I have to do this ?

```
json_object *jobj = json_tokener_parse(...);

...

json_object_put(jobj);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [json_object_new_object](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#af0ed3555604f39ac74b5e28bc5b1f82c) says

> Remember, when using json_object_object_add or json_object_array_put_idx, ownership will transfer to the object/array.

and

> Any ownerships you acquired but did not transfer must be released through json_object_put.

To me, that means this should be okay:

```
json_object *jobj1 = json_object_new_object();
json_object *jobj2 = json_object_new_object();

json_object_object_add(jobj1, "Object", jobj2);

// ...

json_object_put(jobj1); // This is the only one we have ownership of now
```

And yes, like the documentation says, you *must* release all your ownerships using `json_object_put`.

Regarding [json_tokener_parse](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__tokener_8h.html#abf031fdf1e5caab71e2225a99588c6bb), the documentation doesn't explicitly say anything about ownership or releasing, but I would be *very* surprised if it was different `json_object_new_object` in that respect. It wouldn't make any sense if you weren't allowed to use objects returned from `json_tokener_parse` the same way you can use objects constructed through `json_object_new_object`.

For instance, it should be possible to do this:

```
json_object *jobj1 = json_object_new_object();  // "Manual" object
json_object *jobj2 = json_tokener_parse(...);   // Parsed object

// At this point, jobj1->_ref_count and jobj2->_ref_count will both be 1.

// We could now add the parsed object as a new field in our "manual" one:
json_object_object_add(jobj1, "ParsedObject", jobj2); 

// ...

// In the end, we only have to release the "manual" object.
json_object_put(jobj1);
```

Also, yes, as your valgrind log indicates, the `json_tokener_parse` function calls `json_object_new_object` behind the scenes, so you need to call `json_object_put` for the returned object (i.e., unless you incorporate it into another object or array, as mentioned earlier).

The guy who wrote the code in the referenced [blog post](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/json_parser_json-c/) doesn't seem to care about the memory leak in his program, perhaps because that program is so simple and ends immediately after processing only one object.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Do you also confirm that `json_object_put` must be called when we have finished with `json_tokener_parse`?

Comment: @fralbo: Yes, I have updated my answer to also address the part about json_tokener_parse. I have also verified my claims by actually looking at the source code for json-c at https://github.com/json-c/json-c

Comment: Please don't use the doc links mentioned above, start from http://json-c.github.io/json-c/ instead.